# How can I make a slideshow with tabbed navigation/menu?

Tags: javascript, views

I'm trying to make a slideshow that looks something like this
[image: Slideshow example]

I'm using views slideshow but I could change it up if need be. Preferably views though.

My problem is the navigation to the right. I have created a content type for this slideshow and fields for the image, the green title and the black subtitle. The slideshow should run by itself and highlight the proper menu item in the sidebar, but also allow for the user to change slide by clicking a menu item.

Any ideas on if and how this could be done?

Comment: I imported the image into the question, but please consider setting a better title on the question yourself.

Comment: Didn't know how to include it. Changed the title to make it clearer.

Comment: I don't think you have enough reputation to be allowed to inline images yet, but on the other hand I couldn't find a reference on that in the privileges list. So I included it for you, I do expect people to write useful titles though, so that I won't fix for others ;)

Comment: Yes you are right I should have written a better title. Anyway, there I fixed it! :)

Answer (score 2):

In most Views slideshows I've seen, the navigation is just part of the normal slideshow, but themed to not overlap, unlike the images.

Configure the View to select whatever information you need in the navigation, end then make your theme place the navigation to the right.

I would be surprised if VS does not already have functionality for connecting clicks on some elements with sliding to a certain image, but I don't know the ins and outs of the module enough to give more specific recommendations.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input. My main problem seems to be that I can't get the pagers to be anything else than the standard dots. 

I do pick pager > pager type : fields > title:

But I still get the dots :(

Answer (score 0):

In the settings for the slideshow, under Format > Slideshow | Settings you need to add a pager widget (top or bottom is up to you). When you check the Pager checkbox, more options open up. The Pager Type is Fields by default and under that are a list of fields that have been added to the view already. You can select one or more of those fields and the fields you choose will become your pager.

Screenshot:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0gUI3V589rmcEJJOExCRjFpR1k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yeah I'm trying this, but it's not working. I'm getting dots as pagers no matter how I do. 

This is correct right?

http://oi44.tinypic.com/291izhe.jpg

Comment: It could be that you are just seeing the li dots. Can you provide a screenshot of the view preview?

Comment: Nahh those are real pagers, there's a div for each one of them with classes such as "views-slideshow-pager-field-item-dot-filled". 

Here is an image from within views, the pagers don't show here for some reason. http://oi39.tinypic.com/2ihxohf.jpg

And here is an image from the site:
http://oi39.tinypic.com/72xhf8.jpg

Comment: I exported my view so you could import it and see what I've done: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0gUI3V589rmUHFCTW5hR3BobkU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How do I use this? I can't find any import options.

Comment: /admin/structure/views/import

Comment: I'm just getting an empty admin page there with the admin bar but nothing else. 

http://oi44.tinypic.com/e19004.jpg

Comment: What version of Drupal and Views are you using?

Comment: Drupal 7. Views 3.x-7.x-dev.

I just noticed that the dot's are from the CSS. I've inherited this theme and page from another developer so I'm not so used to it yet.

Anyway, the two pager divs where styled as dots. But even removing that styling, they don't show anything since there is nothing beeing outputted in the pager divs for some reason.

Comment: is the views UI module enabled?

Comment: Yeah it's activated.

Comment: Then I have no idea what to tell you!

Comment: It's ok you did your best! :)

Comment: I got this now. I updated to the latest dev-version of views slideshow, cleared my cash - and tada! The titles appear as pagers when I chooose them.

Comment: Thats great news